# Elasticsearch drops 'ings' part of the word, when storing the term 'Dumplings'

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic search index with the words "Paneer Dumplings". However elastic drops the 'ings' part of Dumplings and stores only 'dumpl'. Because of this when I search for dumplings, it returns nothing. How can I get it to store the full word 'Dumplings' ?

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X GET "localhost:9200/my-index/_termvectors/1234?fields=name" | jq .

{
  "_index": "my-index",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1234",
  "_version": 1563,
  "found": true,
  "took": 0,
  "term_vectors": {
    "name": {
      "field_statistics": {
        "sum_doc_freq": 25997,
        "doc_count": 4039,
        "sum_ttf": 26756
      },
      "terms": {
        "dumpl": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 1,
              "start_offset": 7,
              "end_offset": 16
            }
          ]
        },
        "paneer": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 0,
              "start_offset": 0,
              "end_offset": 6
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the mappings I have used analyzer 'english'

```
mappings: {
        dynamic: false,
        properties: {
            name: { type: "search_as_you_type", "analyzer": "english", "search_analyzer": "search_soundex" },
```

I have used standard tokenizer.

```
{
    settings: {
        analysis: {
            analyzer: {
                search_soundex: {
                    tokenizer: "standard",
                    filter: [
                        "lowercase"
                        , "graph_synonyms"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "graph_synonyms": {
                    "type": "synonym_graph",
                    "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonyms.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using [English analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) for `name` field, `"Paneer Dumplings"` will get tokenized to

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "paneer",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "dumpl",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 16,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Now when you are trying to search for `dumplings` you will not get any result as there is no document in the index that match with `dumplings`.

---

If you want the result to match with `dumplings` then you should use [edge_ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "search_soundex": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 5,
          "max_gram": 6,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "search_as_you_type",
        "analyzer": "english",
        "search_analyzer": "search_soundex"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name": "Paneer Dumplings"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Dumplings"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67430644",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Paneer Dumplings"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: stemming which is the root cause of the truncation is useful in majority of cases, (eg: to treat plural and singular forms alike), but produces non-sense in few cases like this. So I was hoping more in line of stem_exclusion

Comment: @AshokKumar if you want to search for `Dumplings` then you have to use the `edge_ngram` tokenizer. But if you want to include an `english` analyzer also then you can use the concept of multifield. It would be better if you can share some sample index data and expected search result, so that I can provide a working example for the same